# Can i launch application on iPhone 4 which written on Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Can i launch application on iPhone 4 which written on Swift? And can it launch on iOS 6 or iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Swift will run on iOS 7 devices.

Comment: and exactly on (iPhone 4) with iOS7?